# Binary Polynomial Factoring

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, factoring, coding-theory

I just need confirmation that I've done my math right.

If $a(x) = x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$ and $b(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ are binary polynomials, find binary polynomials s(x) and r(x) such that

$x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 = s(x)(x^2 + x + 1) + r(x)$, where $r(x)$ is of degree at most $1$.

$s(x)$ can be $x$ or $x + 1$

if $s(x) = x$, then $r(x)$ would be $x^3$

if $s(x) = x + 1$, then $r(x)$ would be $x + 1$

Which one is correct? Would they both be correct?

Comment: For division of polynomials, the degree of the remainder should be strictly less than the degree of the divisor.

Comment: so x^3 is out? The answer would be s(x) = x+1, r(x) = x+1 ?

Comment: Actually, as I look at it, I think neither of your choices is correct.  Have you tried long division?

Comment: What if we did s(x) = (x^2 - 1) and r(x) = (2x+2)?!?

Comment: In binary, $2x+2$ is $0$.

Comment: $x^4+x^3+x+1$ is of degree fours and the divisor $x^2+x+1$ of degree two so $s(x)$ should be of degree $4-2=2$. As you observed, $s(x)=x^2+1$ leads to a remainder $r(x)=0$. With a little bit of practice you can see the factorizations:
$$x^4+x^3+x+1=x^3(x+1)+(x+1)=(x^3+1)(x+1)$$
and
$$x^3+1=x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=(x+1)(x^2+x+1),$$
so $x^4+x^3+x+1=(x+1)^2(x^2+x+1)$ verifying the calculation.